# Processor affinity on Linux using taskset

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cpu, taskset

I have the following code in a bash script:

```
echo "bash pid => $$";
echo "processor affinity before => $(taskset -p $$)"
taskset -cp ${AN_INTEGER} $$
echo "processor affinity after => $(taskset -p $$)"
```

I get this output:

```
processor affinity before => pid 5047's current affinity mask: ff
pid 5047's current affinity list: 0-7
pid 5047's new affinity list: 1
processor affinity after => pid 5047's current affinity mask: 2
```

does anyone know what this means?

The reason I started messing with processor affinity is because I would launch multiple bash child processes, and all the bash child process affinities had the value "ff" so it seemed like they were all targeting the same CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The affinity **mask** controls the *set* of processors that a process may run on - not a single specific processor. Bits that are a 1 in this mask mean represent a processor that the process can run on. Since you specified that you want this process run on only CPU 1, the affinity mask is now 0b00000010, or 2.

Comment: huh, I guess I could look up the difference between affinity list vs. affinity mask